# How to load a set of images stored in a zip file?

Tags: python, zip

I'm a beginner in Machine Learning and want to play around with some image classification code from github with the data I have. I am having problem loading the image data in python. Problem being - I don't know how. How would I load the data and format it?

Comment: How does this has anything to do with deep-learning or conda?

Comment: Python's [documentation index](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html#cap-z) shows it has several of `zip` related modules. I'm guessing the [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile) module would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "read" is vague, but here is an example which reads a jpeg file using the Image class, and prints information about it.

```
import os,sys 
import Image 
jpgfile = Image.open("picture.jpg")

print jpgfile.bits, jpgfile.size, jpgfile.format
```